# Second checkbox not showing up even though its identical?

Tags: html, css

```
<div id="Box">  
    <div id="emailtextbox"><input  type="text" size="40" /></div>
    <div id="CheckBox1"><input type="checkbox" Name="Mr."/>Mr.</div>
    <div id="CheckBox2"><input type="checkbox" Name="Mrs."/>Mrs.</div>
</div>
```

CheckBox 1 shows up, but CheckBox2 doesn't. Using css I changed the location of both checkboxes to make sure they weren't stacked on top of each other, but that doesn't appear to be the problem. They're identical so I don't understand why only one of them shows up.

Here's the css if it helps:

```
#CheckBox1 {
    margin-top: 700px;
    width: 200px;

}
#CheckBox2 {
    margin-top: 700px;
    width: 400px;
}
```

Comment: It is shown but at the bottom of the page since u have margin-top:700px http://jsfiddle.net/f06L0u7v/

Comment: Check out this [link](https://jsfiddle.net/98fkha45/)JSFiddle

Comment: You should also consider using a radio type input instead of checkbox, since it is unlikely that both should be checked.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

remove

```
#CheckBox1 {
    margin-top: 700px;
}
#CheckBox2 {
    margin-top: 700px;
}
```

Comment: That fixed the problem, but now my checkboxes are all over the place. Any ideas on how to align them?

Comment: hi can you try this in your css : #CheckBox1,#CheckBox2 {   
   float: left;
   margin: 10px 10px 0 0;
}

Answer (score 0):

check out this, your css only making issue

remove

```
margin-top: 700px;
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vasanthanvas/L9pprwk5/)

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the huge margins from the style, they do show!

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you are using too much of a margin-top and it's going passed the parent div height. Change the `margin-top` to 5px.

**CSS**

```
#CheckBox1 {
    margin-top: 5px; 
    width: 200px;

}
#CheckBox2 {
    margin-top: 5px;
    width: 400px;
}
```